# Get current Environment name

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an AWS question: I have an application running on Beanstalk. I have two environments, XXX-LIVE and XXX-TEST.

I would like to know how I can get the Environment name using the SDK, since I want to point to my test database if the code is running on the XXX-TEST environment?

So far I have only found the .RetrieveEnvironmentInfo() method of the object AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonElasticBeanstalkClient();

But this requires that you provide the Environment name/ID.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add custom "environment-name" parameter to both environments. Set the value to the name of the environment or just specify "test" or "production".

[image]

If the database access URL is the only difference between the two, then set URL as a parameter and you will end up with identical code with no branches.

More details on customization can be found here: [Customizing and Configuring AWS Elastic Beanstalk Environments](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers.html)

Answer (score 4):

Here's how we do it for our application in ruby:

```
  def self.beanstalk_env
    begin
      uuid = File.readlines('/sys/hypervisor/uuid', 'r')
      if uuid
        str = uuid.first.slice(0,3)
        if str == 'ec2'
          metadata_endpoint = 'http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/'
          dynamic_endpoint = 'http://169.254.169.254/latest/dynamic/'
          instance_id = Net::HTTP.get( URI.parse( metadata_endpoint + 'instance-id' ) )
          document = Net::HTTP.get( URI.parse( dynamic_endpoint + 'instance-identity/document') )
          parsed_document = JSON.parse(document)
          region = parsed_document['region']
          ec2 = AWS::EC2::Client.new(region: region)
          ec2.describe_instances({instance_ids:[instance_id]}).reservation_set[0].instances_set[0].tag_set.each do |tag|
            if tag.key == 'elasticbeanstalk:environment-name'
              return tag.value
            end
          end
        end
      end
    rescue

    end
    'No_Env'
  end
```

Your instance's IAM-policy will have to allow ec2:describe:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": [
        "ec2:Describe*"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```